# Stopped Ubuntu UI installation. Need to reverse all changes

Tags: server, gui

I started to install the Ubuntu UI on my server using `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`, but decided I didn't want it. I've stopped it via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> but how can I reverse any changes that happened on my machine?

Comment: It's unwise to interrupt the package manager, as a non-graceful termination may leave dpkg's view of the system different from reality. That may cause problems later. Please edit your question to explain exactly which commands you used to "install the Ubuntu UI." If you were following directions, a link to those directions would be helpful.

Comment: Not really anything else to add, other than the command I used. I was installing the desktop, decided I didn't want to use it, cancelled it, and now I need to reverse those changes. I understand I more than likely made a boo-boo. Question updated with the command used. Can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverse the install with:

```
sudo apt-get remove ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

Check /var/log/apt/term.log for the complete list of packages that were installed during your session. All should be removed by the autoremove command.

Some of those packages may have left setting files in /etc. An ordinary 'remove' won't remove those, hence the '--purge'.

Note: In Ubuntu 16.04 and newer, you can use `apt` in place of `apt-get` for these commands. Since your original command used apt-get, the fix uses the same commands merely to prevent confusion.

Note for future readers: 'Purge' is NOT a magic 'force' command. 'remove' cannot remove files in /etc, 'purge' can. That's the ONLY difference.

Comment: Much obliged sir!

Comment: Just some update on this (and a forewarning to ubuntu newbies like myself): Don't ever cancel the installation of `ubuntu-desktop`. After a reboot after making these fixes, I was stuck at the login screen and couldn't move or type anything. Wound up having to do a new fresh install of Ubuntu Server

Comment: Well, how about we change that to: Don't ever interrupt a package manager, period. Wait for it to complete, then reverse the action.

Comment: Well that works as well. Productive hours down the drain for me!